# update and concatenate columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update and concatenate 3 columns in a new a attribute I've already created in my table. However when I execute my code, it puts attributes that before had values in `null`.

My code example:

```
update saber2012_1
    set estu_fecha_nacimiento = Concat(estu_nacimiento_dia,'/',estu_nacimiento_mes,'/',estu_nacimiento_anno);
```

In this picture all values that is in `null` before these had values.

[image]

when I make this update

```
ALTER TABLE saber2012_uno ADD COLUMN punt_c_naturales int;
update saber2012_uno set punt_c_naturales = round((PUNT_BIOLOGIA::numeric + PUNT_FISICA::numeric + PUNT_QUIMICA::numeric) / 3,0); 
alter table saber2012_uno DROP COLUMN PUNT_BIOLOGIA; 
alter table saber2012_uno DROP COLUMN PUNT_FISICA;
alter table saber2012_uno DROP COLUMN PUNT_QUIMICA;
```

all is well. but I do not know because previous update is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want `concat_ws()`:

```
update saber2012_1
    set estu_fecha_nacimiento = concat_ws('/', estu_nacimiento_dia, estu_nacimiento_mes, estu_nacimiento_anno);
```

This will ignore any of the arguments that are `NULL`.

However, your update will not change any other columns in the table.  Perhaps the results are just coming back in a different order, when you query after the update.

Comment: Hello, thanks. whit your solution now is there are less nulls rows. but still i have this problem. I do not what happen... :( one question ? the attributes have to be the same type.... estu_fecha_nacimiento  is varchar(200) and other attributes are text. can it be problem ?

Comment: @juancamilovallejos0- maybe,try making it the same

Comment: @juancamilovallejos0 . . . I think the data is unaltered, just the order of the rows changes.